# How to treat a Makefile with another name in vim?

Tags: vim, makefile

I am working in a library that has its own Makefile, so I am using my own Makefile called `my_makefile` and use `make -f my_makefile`

My problem is how to tell Vim that `my_makefile` is an actual Makefile and use color scheme that it use for a Makefile.

It is hard to read it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also have found another way! You can use "my_makefile.mk" and vim automatically know it is a MakeFile and you do not need to change .vimrc either.

Answer (score 7):

How about the

```
:set syntax=make
```

command

Comment: That works! Thanks

How can I add it to my .vimrc? any idea?

Comment: If the extension of all your custom makefiles is the same, you can create an `autocmd`.

    `autocmd Bufenter *cust set syntax=make`

where *cust is matching for the filename.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use [Modelines](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Modeline_magic), which are comments in either the first 5 or last 5 lines of a file that vim reads, and are used to set the filetype. For example, in a makefile, it would be:

```
# vim: filetype=make
```

Comment: Awesome!!
It is about 6 years I am working with vim and I have never heard of Modelines!